# How can I disable a button without calling the setState method in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I want to disable the raised button whenever an user enters mobile number less than 10 digit.
After the user enters 10 digit mobile number then it will be enabled but if in case the number becomes less than 10 digit it will again be disable. Currently i am doing that with the help of a set state method.But I don't think so it is feasible as the build function is called time and again . This is my code.

```
TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (val){
                      number='+91' + val;
                      if(number.length==13){

                        setState(() {
                          numberlessthanten=false;
                        });
                      }
                         else{

                        setState(() {
                          numberlessthanten=true;
                        });

                      }
                    },

child: RaisedButton(

                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        onPressed: numberlessthanten ? null : (){
                          print(number);
                          _sumbit();

                        },

                            child: Text('Send Code'),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your textformfield use a controller.
`TextFormField( controller = _controller )`
Now in your raised button.

```
RaisedButton(
 onPressed: _controller.length <10?null:(){}
  child:Text("send Code")
 )
```

Comment: This will still trigger the build function.

Comment: triggering the build function is normal

Comment: I know. But that was the question. Your code triggers the build function just as many times as theirs. You may want to explain why yours is better when it does the same thing.

Comment: I'm not calling setSate two times. I'm just using a single line of code.

Comment: But you do realize that the `build` method is called just as often as in the question and that the OP was worried about that, right? Don't get me wrong, your answer is not wrong in any way, it's just that the OP might assume that since there is no direct call to `setState` that your solution magically manages to avoid that. And it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. And should not. You *are* changing state. You might find a functionality that hides the `setState` call from you, so you don't have it in your code directly, but in the end, that functionality *will* call `setState`.

It's perfectly normal to call the build function multiple times.

For performance considerations, there is a paragraph [in the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).